# Variable (token) holding parsed token is returning nil

Tags: go, jwt

My `VerifyToken` is returning `nil` and, despite many attempts, I have been unable to discover why.

Also in each `function(ExtractToken(),VerifyToken())` I tried to print out the token to confirm if the token exists. The parsed token from the `VerifyToken` `func` is `nil` and I had tried ways to make it work but it still returning `nil`.

My `.env` file contains:

```
ACCESS_SECRET = "jdnfksdmfksd"
REFRESH_SECRET = "mcmvmkmsdnfsdmfdsjf"
```

And my application code follows:

```golang
//types.TokenDetails
type TokenDetails struct {
    AccessToken  string
    AccessUuid   string
    UserId       uint64
    AtExp        int64
    RefreshToken string
    RefreshUuid  string
    RtExp        int64
}

func CreateToken(userId uint64, r *http.Request) (*types.TokenDetails, error) {
    var err error

    td := &types.TokenDetails{}
    td.AccessUuid = uuid.NewV4().String()
    //td.UserId = userId
    td.AtExp = time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 15).Unix()

    atClaims := jwt.MapClaims{}
    atClaims["authorization"] = true
    atClaims["access_uuid"] = td.AccessUuid
    atClaims["user_id"] = userId
    atClaims["exp"] = td.AtExp

    at := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, atClaims)
    td.AccessToken, err = at.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("ACCESS_SECRET")))

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    td.RefreshUuid = uuid.NewV4().String()
    td.RtExp = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 7).Unix()

    rfClaims := jwt.MapClaims{}
    rfClaims["refresh_uuid"] = td.RefreshUuid
    rfClaims["exp"] = td.RtExp
    fClaims["user_id"] = userId

    ft := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, rfClaims)
    td.RefreshToken, err = ft.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("REFRESH_SECRET")))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return td, nil

}


func ExtractToken(r *http.Request) string {
    bearToken := r.Header.Get("authorization")
    tokenString := strings.Split(bearToken, " ")
    fmt.Println("Bear Token", bearToken)// tried to debug here and its not empty

    if len(tokenString) == 2 {
        return tokenString[1]
    }
    return ""
}

func VerifyToken(r *http.Request) (*jwt.Token, error) {
    tokenString := ExtractToken(r)
    fmt.Println(tokenString)//tried to debug here and is not empty

    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        //Make sure that the token method conform to "SigningMethodHMAC"
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }
        return []byte(os.Getenv("ACCESS_SECRET")), nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return token, nil
}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (should only need a version of `VerifyToken` and a call to it with the appropriate arguments - none of the other code is relevant). Have you confirmed that `os.Getenv("ACCESS_SECRET")` is returning what you expect? What is the value of `err`?

Comment: @Brits, ok have understood you ,the value of the err is : {
    "Inner": {},
    "Errors": 20
}

Comment: In your `ExtractToken` func, you have a `return ""` statement. So in `VerifyToken` when calling `tokenString := ExtractToken(r)` if the len(tokenString) is not 2, it will pass an nil sting. Try using a vscode debugger and step by step watch what is happening with your variables.

Comment: @Cloudziu,the ExtractToken is not return nil, its returning string i confirmed it, BUT when the string is passed to jwt.Parse() then the variable assigns to jwt.Parse() becomes nil and it return nil .

Comment: @MusaAbdulhameed please give us a working example; something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/QgHMoeqOgoU) (which demonstrates that the important part of your code can work).